# Why is my Angular template throwing this Typescript error?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm building an `Angular 4` project in `Typescript 2.3.4`. I can't figure out what's wrong with the code below.

**IDialog interface**

```
export interface IDialog{
    cancellable?: boolean,     

    inputs?: Array<{label: string, value?: any, description?: string}|string>
    message: string
    title?: string,
    type?: DialogInputTypes // <- an Enum
}
```

**SampleComponent.ts**

```
  public dialog:IDialog = {
    cancellable:false,
    title:'Dialog Title',
    message:'This is a modal dialog',
    type:DialogInputTypes.button,
    inputs:[
      {label:'OK', value:'OK'},
      {label:'Cancel', value:'Cancel'}
    ]
  };
```

**SampleComponent.html**

```
<input *ngFor="let input of dialog.inputs" [value]="input.value">
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This error is thrown by the compiler:

> Angular: Identifier 'value' is not defined. `<anonymous>` does not contain such a member

I just upgraded from `Angular 2` with `Typescript 2.0` and this error was not present before.

Why is this error thrown? Perhaps it has to do with the fact that IDialog.inputs is defined as either an array or a string, and at compile time there is no way for the compiler to know which shape inputs has. If I remove `|string` from the interface, the error goes away.

More importantly, I don't know how to fix my code.

Comment: I wonder if `[value]="input.value"` should be `[value]="input?value"` since that is how it is declared in the interface.

Comment: Thanks. Using `input?.value` makes no difference. I think the error has to do with the fact that `IDialog.inputs` is defined as either an array or a string, and at compile time there is no way for the compiler to know which shape `inputs` has. I'm just speculating though

Comment: I agree with @BeetleJuice, I suspect it has to do with the "|string" as part of the IDialog interface. You'll need to cast it to the right type.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It's easy to test though, just remove that `|string` and see if the error is still there.

Comment: @HarryNinh If I remove `|string` the error goes away, but that's not a solution because sometimes that member is a string. So making this change will throw errors elsewhere.

Comment: If that is the case, you would want to change your template anyway, what if the inputs contains a string and everything will screw up.

Comment: @HarryNinh my mistake. It's never a string. Sometimes it's an array of strings, as the OP interface shows. However in the context of this component, I know it will always be an `Array<{label:string, value:string}` because this is hard-coded (see the `SampleComponent`  code section in the OP)

Comment: Please reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely your project configuration 
Your code works perfectly fine if its like this

```js
@Component({
   template: `
       <input *ngFor="let input of dialog.inputs" [value]="input.value">
   `
})
export class WhateverComponent{
    public dialog:IDialog = {
        inputs:[
            {label:'OK', value:'OK'},
            {label:'Cancel', value:'Cancel'}
        ]
    };
}
export interface IDialog{
    inputs: Array<iSomeControl | string >;
}
export interface iSomeControl{
    label: string;
    value: string;

}
```

I am using Angular 4.0.2 Typescript 2.2.2
I modified in order to be more specific

Comment: Changing the interface is not the solution I want. The interface as it's written in the OP shows the correct shape of `IDialog.inputs`. Sometimes it's an array, sometimes it's a string. If I just change it to `Array<any>`, errors will be thrown elsewhere where `inputs` is used as a string

Comment: I am not an expert but the label , value , description are an anonymous Array or are they a specific type ? My guess is if they are anonymous the compiler doesnt know how to pick between an anonymous Array or a string

Comment: This is happening for me with simple strings: `{value:string, message: string, description:string}[]`

Answer (score 0):

Disable angular extension pack and angular language service plugins from VS code.

I had a similar problem and this solved it.

Comment: I would not want to do that because I find the angular language service very valuable: it allows autocomplete and type checking of component properties while I write my template. It was just this specific situation that I found annoying. I think I downgraded from `typescript 2.3.4` to `typescript 2.3.3` to address this, but I don't remember clearly.