# Angular 4 template error: 'anonymous' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

`Angular 4` written in `Typescript 2.3.4`

**component.ts**

```
/**
 * Info that drives the tabs in the template. Array is filled
 * in ngOnInit() once data is received from the server
 */
public tabs:Array<{
  title:string,
  description:string,
  data:Array<{name:string}>
}>=[];
```

**component.html**

```
<section *ngFor="let t of tabs">
  ...
  <div *ngFor="let i of t.data">{{i.name}}</div>
                                  ^^^^^^
</section>
```

**Compiler error**

> Angular: Identifier 'name' is not defined. `<anonymous>` does not contain such a member

At first I thought this was linked to [my other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915015/why-is-my-angular-template-throwing-this-typescript-error) but this is different because there is no ambiguity in the shape of the `tabs` model: the component clearly shows that `name` is a property of each member of the `data` array, itself a property of each member of `tabs` array.

What's going on here?

Comment: where you assign data into tabs? please post here. bcz i test your code working fine

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor Even if I never assign anything (eg: if I delete my `ngOnInit()`), this error is raised; so the error is not caused by how the data is assiigned to `tabs`. Remember, the error occurs in my code editor, not at runtime so it doesn't have anything to do with the data that came back from the server

Comment: i test your code but working fine. assign dayta tabs in onNgInit() and print it in tamplate/.

Comment: Are you using plugin language service? Which editor are you using?

Comment: @yurzui I am not. Thanks to @ShaileshLadumor's [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/E3AI78mUXEGiXx7Hlm3S?p=preview), I'm able to see that it has something to do with the Typescript version. His demo works well, but if you change the TS version (line 44 of `config.js`) to the version I used in the OP (`2.3.4`), the app will crash

Comment: I'm getting this same error using the Angular Language Service extension with VS Code. I think it's a bug in Angular Language Service but I haven't found any workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Safe Navigation Operator (?) in the binding, which allows you to navigate an object path in situations where the path may or may not be initially valid.

```
  <div *ngFor="let i of t.data">{{i?.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**solution worked !** 
that gives me this message :

> **Identifier 'question' is not defined. '' does not contain such a member**

plus underline this

```
<div class="card-header">
          {{q.question}}  <!- underline this line with red color -->
            ^^^^^^^^^^
</div>
```

it's a typescript problem and **you have to declare tabs as an any type** to avoid this problem 
 `tabs : any [];`

Comment: Declaring the type as `any` gets rid of all typing support for that variable.  Because I use the variable elsewhere (in my typescript files, not just the template) I would like to keep its type well-defined.  This is not a good solution for me but am glad it worked for you. Thanks for sharing.